# VLC Stream Script chain failed

Tags: bash, vlc

I've tried to create a script that saves a stream to an mp4 using h264. The part after the --sout was extracted from the GUI in the Stream wizard.

My problem is:
The stream does not display or save, 
and
it does not get variable i set as filename

```
#!/bin/bash
#date
#date +"%c"
#var=$(date)
#var=`date`

#now=$date
#echo "$now"
date +"%m_%d_%Y"
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
_now=$(date +"%T_%d_%m_%Y")
_file="vidlecture_$_now.mp4"
vlc -vvv tcp://1.1.1.1:3000 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=$file.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=display}:no-sout-all:sout-keep"
```

This is the error I get:

```
[9f30dbe0] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=display}:no-sout-all:sout-keep'
[9f20f3f0] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
[01d3c6e0] main playlist debug: dead input
[01d3c6e0] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[01d3c6e0] main playlist debug: nothing to play
```

EDIT:

I updated my script and error here to reflect @Aaron's comment which helped me to fix the filename variable. 
Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#date
#date +"%c"
#var=$(date)
#var=`date`

#now=$date
#echo "$now"
date +"%m_%d_%Y"
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
_now=$(date +"%T_%d_%m_%Y")
_file="vidlecture_$_now.mp4"
vlc -vvv tcp://1.1.1.1:3000 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=$_file.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=display}:no-sout-all:sout-keep"
```

Error:

```
[9f30da80] main stream output debug: stream=`sout-keep'
[9f30dc80] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "sout-keep": 23 candidates
[9f30dc80] main stream out debug: no sout stream modules matched
[9f30dc80] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
[9f30dc80] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[9f30da80] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=vidlecture_11:30:58_09_03_2020.mp4.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=display}:no-sout-all:sout-keep'
[9f20f390] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

Comment: You use `$file.mp4` in your `--sout` value but you previously defined `_file` rather than `file`. You can see `duplicate{dst=file{dst=.mp4,no-overwrite}` in the VLC error

Comment: @Aaron You're absolutely correct. I fixed the variable now which is reflected in my edited file output. However it still does not stream.

Comment: The error is still the same?

Comment: @Aaron it gives me the same error, however it now does reflect the variable as filename in the error (see the updated question)

Comment: The error is actually quite different now. It now complains about the `sout-keep` part at the end of your `--sout` : it expects to find a module named this way but it doesn't. I'm not familiar with VLC scripting and searching for `sout-keep` I only found a [command-line option](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#Keeping_the_stream_open). Maybe it would make sense to remove `:sout-keep` from the `--sout` and use the `-sout-keep` option instead? Hope someone familiar with VLC can help you

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I removed both --sout related parameters at the end and now it works. as I expect it to. I will still do some further testing and come back with some results

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for jumping in, but not much results for those who encounter this issue as a programmer.

if you have this issue, the solution is to remove the prefix ":sout=..."

e.g.

instead of `":sout=#transcode{vcodec..."`

this works: `"#transcode{vcodec..."`

Hope that helps any programmer out there..

Comment: Thanks! You literally saved my life...

Comment: removing 'sout' means removing the ability to stream out. the video may play, but won't stream out.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked:

> --sout "#std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=output.mp4}"

or for both destinations (display and file)

> --sout "#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=output.mp4}}"